# Compose Multiplatform MaterialTheme not reflecting custom fonts

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I have created a custom AppTheme in my Kotlin Multiplatform project using Jetpack Compose. I'm trying to apply custom fonts to the MaterialTheme typography, but the fonts are not reflecting in my text views. However, when I directly use the custom font family in the Text composable, it works fine.

Here's how I've set up my AppTheme function in the commonMain module:

```
@Composable
fun AppTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val fontFamilyNunitoRegular = fontFamilyResource(MR.fonts.Nunito.regular)
    val fontFamilyNunitoBold = fontFamilyResource(MR.fonts.Nunito.bold)

    MaterialTheme(
        typography = Typography(
            // ... other text styles
            displaySmall = TextStyle(
                fontFamily = fontFamilyNunitoBold,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 24.sp
            ),
            // ... other text styles
        ),
        content = content
    )}
```

I have wrapped my root composable with this AppTheme, but the custom font is not being applied to the text views.

However, using the custom font directly in the Text composable works as expected:

```
Text(
    text = "hello world",
    fontFamily = fontFamilyNunitoBold,
    fontSize = 24.sp,
    color = Color(0xFFBBBCFF)
)
```

I'm using the moko resources plugin for resource management, and all the above code is in my commonMain module. I have verified that the font resources MR.fonts.Nunito.regular and MR.fonts.Nunito.bold are correctly defined.

Am I missing something in my AppTheme setup that's preventing the custom fonts from being applied to the entire theme? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typography value is not set in material themed objects the way colors are.

This means setting the text style in the theme alone won’t result in your text style being used by composables wrapped by your material theme.

The text style in composables is set to LocalTextStyle.current (you can see this by inspecting a material text composable with ctrl + b) this means the composable will look up the compose tree and find the nearest place you have set the localTextStyle.current.

You can set the localtextStyle.current with the following line

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextStyle provides 
MaterialTheme.typography.displaySmall
    ) {
           Text("this text and its child nodes will inherit the displaySmall text style")
}
```

This will set the style through all child composables - however it may just be easier to set the style explicitly in your composables.

```
Text("this composable will use the displaySmall style”, style = MaterialTheme.typography.displaySmall)
```